# Can't open files with arabic or german letters from Dolphin - Arch

Tags: arch-linux, dolphin

I am using Dolphin as my file manager in Arch.

Whenever I try to open a `pdf` with an arabic name or has german letters like `ä/ö/`..., it opens the index `file:///` in the browser.

The file name itself is not written, only `/` is written or `.pdf`.

I can't find anything on the internet that solves that problem. The fonts and language packages are downloaded so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Edit:
Output of `locale`

```
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=en_VG.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Could you create a new user account and check if it affects them as well?

Comment: yes it also doesn't open

Comment: @Yasmeen It may not be just a dolphin thing, what happens if you choose the file to be opened with a pdf viewer?

Comment: yea that also doesn't work, it shows me an empty window

Comment: If Dolphin has an option to "Preload", disable it, kill all its processes, run it from a terminal (e.g. Konsole) and check if there are any errors. Please, don't answer questions with "Yes, No ..." - it's really confusing, it's not how English is used. Maybe it's in your culture but you speak a foreign language with its own culture. Just don't add "Yes, " in the beginning of your answers.

Comment: there are no errors in the terminal but it still opens the index in the browser. I tried using a pdf viewer and it says `Unable to open ""`, with an empty file name. So I think that's the main reason...